# model form not rendering in django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

My **models.py** and this is my model for photos.

```
       # home photo page
    class Photos(models.Model):
        photo_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
        photo_description = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
        photo_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
        photo_location = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
        photo_file = models.FileField(upload_to='photos', blank=False)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.photo_title
```

My **forms.py** this is the **model form** I made to render it as a form.

```
    class UploadPhotosForm(forms.Form):
    
        class Meta:
            model = Photos
            fields = '__all__'
```

my **views.py** these are my relavent imports and section I coded in view file.

```
from .forms import CampForm, ProjectForm, HikeForm, UploadPostsForm, UploadPhotosForm

    posts = UploadPostsForm()
    photo = UploadPhotosForm()

    print(photo.as_p())
```

here this code should print the form as text into console isn't it?
But I don't have any console output. It seems like the nothing has been initialized to the `photo` variable isn't it?
I do not have any clue what happened.

```
    context = {
        'title': 'manage_wall',
        'posts': posts,
        'photo': photo,
    }
    return render(request, 'manager/manage_wall.html', context)
```

My **template**

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <form action="" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{photo.as_p}}
                <input type="submit" value="Add">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <form action="" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{posts.as_p}}
                <input type="submit" value=" Add">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{%endblock %}
```

[image]

As you can see here my `photoForm` is not rendering in the frontend can someone point out the mistake I have made not to render that form only while other forms are successfully rendering in the frontend. My Question is all other model forms rendered successfully why this is not displaying properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **`UploadPhotosForm`** is inherited from **[`forms.Form(...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form)**
class which does not contain **`model`** in **`Meta`** class so instead of inheriting from **`forms.Form`** class inherit from **[`form.ModelForm(...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)**

here is final version of your code

```
 class UploadPhotosForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Photos
         fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Thak you for spending your valuable to answer my bad question. I am very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in **models.py** it should be `forms.ModelForm`

```py
class UploadPhotosForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photos
        fields = '__all__'
```

it is not rendering unless it is a `ModelForm`